# Profile 2 - My account displayed together

Tags: users

i included profile2 into my account page via any settings, and now have realy problem to find where i set it, could someone please help me? It was just one check box, please help me. thx

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to have separate tabs to edit your account information and profile information? If so, edit the profile type and check the "Provide a separate page for editing profiles." option.